# Create a Cassandra keyspace with 'network topology' using Hector?

Tags: cassandra, hector

I want to create a Cassandra keyspace with 'network topology'. I can do it using CLI like this.

```
CREATE KEYSPACE test
WITH placement_strategy = 'NetworkTopologyStrategy'
AND strategy_options={us-east:6,us-west:3};
```

How can I achieve the same using Hector?

Thanks,
Bhathiya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record, this works.

```
Map<String,String> options = new HashMap<String,String>();
options.put("dc1", "3");    
options.put("dc2", "1");    
ThriftKsDef kd = (ThriftKsDef) HFactory.createKeyspaceDefinition(keyspaceName,
     strategyClass, replicationFactor, cfDefs);    
if(options != null){    
     kd.setStrategyOptions(options);    
}    
getCluster().addKeyspace(kd, true);
```

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't do that. Back when Hector was the primary choice for a client driver, the recommendations were that you create your keyspace via the cassandra-CLI

Having said that, I would suggest that you use an up-to-date driver and recomend the [DataStax binary protocol driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver).

Comment: Yes I'm planning to move to java driver soon. Till that I need a way to do this via my application. 
And you said I *shouldn't* do that. Does that mean I still can do that? Is there a way?